# AJAX only populates with final JSON object using jQuery? Circliful jQuery plug in also used

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a JSON file that populates the ajax request, it retrieves the data but only displays the last object value from the JSON file in each div.

Small snippet here - https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/qxctuw47/

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
<div class="grid">
</div>
```

```
<!-- i've simplified the json in comparison to the jsfiddle -->
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "rating": "25",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "rating": "30",
  }
];

jQuery(function($) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    var profile_data = '';
    // ... other code here
    profile_data += '<div class="grid-item grid-item--width3 grid-item--height3 myStat" data-animation="1" data-animationStep="3" data-percent="' + value.rating + '"></div>';
    // append each one within the each loop    
    $('.grid').append(profile_data);
  });
  $(".myStat").circliful({});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make only one instance of `circliful` for all elements having `.myStats` class...

Make an instance for each instead:

```
$(".myStat").each(function(){
  $(this).circliful({});
});
```

Your [Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/4tm15ehv/)